# Ios Swift : Adding or Moving NavigationBar to bottom of the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, frame, navigationbar

I want to move the navigation controller bar to the bottom of the view controller. How can i get this done ?

I tried :

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(
        0,
        UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 50,
        UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,
        50)
```

This is moving to the bottom but hiding all other controller objects and also back button is not woking.

Comment: Are you making use of autolayout constraint ??

Comment: I am not using any autolayout on Navigation Bar, It comes as embeded from previous screen.
I use autolayout only on all View elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sujay U N,

You should not try to move the UINavigationBar provided by the embeded UINavigationController to the bottom of the screen. Trying that will obvisoulsy move all the view's below it causing all the controller objects to hide.

**Workaround**

*Approach 1:*

Consider using ToolBar :)

Toolbar is designed to be placed at the bottom of the screen. If you are using xib or storyboard you can pick toolbar from components library and place it on your ViewController's bottom and then apply autoresizing masks or constraints properly :)

[image]

Now in order to show the back button make use of UIBarButtonItems. Change the style to custom and provide it arrow image or provide default style as done.
[image]

Though now you are all set to go :) You will notice UINavigationBar at the top of your view controller. In order to get rid of it,

select your ViewController, select its TopBar property set it to none :)
[image]

*Approach 2*

Use UINavigationBar.

Specific about using Navigation bar and dont want to use toolbar, well you can do the same thing with UINavigationBar as well.

Drag the UINavigationBar from components library place it at the bottom of the screen. Drag the UIBarButtonItem drop it as leftBarButtonItem, change the barButtonItem image to your back image. ( Same process as UIToolBar just use UINavigationBar instead)

[image]

Understand this is not same as the navigation bar provided by the embeded NavigationController. So get rid of NavigationBar at the top of your ViewController same as I explained above here as well

Finally,

In both the cases, draw an IBoutlet from barbutton item and handle poping the viewController programmatically.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped me

Comment: @sujay-u-n : Glad to know it helped you :) Please consider accepting or up voting the answer as it helped you :)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow, So i do not  have enough reputations to vote.
Please Vote my question up so  i get more reputations,
As soon as i become eligible wil surely vote...